# How to configure CakePHP's $this->Auth->login() to use custom password hasher

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

CakePHP v.2.4...

I'm following [this documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in) trying to set up the Auth component to use my custom password hashing class:

```
App::uses('PHPassPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class AppController extends Controller {

    // auth needed stuff
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Cookie',
        'Auth'      => array(
            'authenticate'      => array(
                'Form'  => array(
                    'fields' => array('username'=>'email', 'password'=>'password'),
                    'passwordHasher'    => 'PHPass' 

                )
            ),
```

Inside my UsersController::login() I debug the return from `$this->Auth->login();` and it always returns false, even when I submit the correct email / password.

(NOTE: It looks strange to me that the `login()` takes no parameters, but the docs seem to imply that it looks into the the request data automatically. And this would make sense if my configurations aren't correctly causing it to check the User.email field instead username.)

The post data from the submitted login form looks like this:

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'email' => 'whatever@example.com'
    )
)
```

What am I missing?

**Update2**

I'm starting to suspect that the default hashing algorithm is getting used instead of my custom class. I tried to match the examples in the docs but they're quite vague on how to do this.

Here's the contents of `app/Controller/Component/Auth/PHPassPasswordHasher.php`

```
<?php
App::import('Vendor', 'PHPass/class-phpass'); //<--this exists and defines PasswordHash class
class PHPassPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher {

    public function hash($password) {
        $hasher = new new PasswordHash( 8, true );
        return $hasher->HashPassword($password);
    }

    public function check($password, $hashedPassword) {
        debug('PHPassHasher'); die('Using custom hasher'); //<--THIS NEVER HAPPENS!
        $hasher = new new PasswordHash( 8, true );
        return $hasher->CheckPassword($password, $hashedPassword);
    }

}
```

**AHA!** The `debug()` never appears... so I'm pretty sure the problem is with my custom hasher configuration(s).

**Update3**

Additional clue: I experimented by setting various default hashing algorithms (Ex: "Simple", "Blowfish") and creating users. The hashes which show up in the DB are all the *same* which tells me that my config settings are getting ignored completely.

**Update4**

I debugged `$this->settings` inside the constructor of /lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php and my custom hasher settings *are* in there:

```
array(
    'fields' => array(
        'password' => 'password',
        'username' => 'email'
    ),
    'userModel' => 'User',
    'scope' => array(),
    'recursive' => (int) 0,
    'contain' => null,
    'passwordHasher' => 'PHPass'
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect your className (and filename) should end with `PasswordHasher`, just like the built-in hashers (https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth). Probably CakePhp is looking for `PHPassHasherPasswordHasher` in your case (which doesn't exist)

Comment: @thaJeztah That's a great idea. I've renamed the class and the file to "PHPassPasswordHasher" but now I'm not sure how to reference it... `App::import('PHPass', ...)`? `App::import('PHPassPasswordHasher`, ...)`? Any ideas?

Comment: @thaJeztah I updated the code above with the new names.

Comment: Saw you got it working, great! CamelCase can be confusing sometimes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rename your password hasher class to have the suffix "PasswordHasher", and only provide the non-suffixed name in the 'className' argument.

eg:

```
<?php
App::import('Vendor', 'PHPass/class-phpass'); //<--this exists and defines PasswordHash class
class PHPassHasherPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher {

    // functions

}
```

The example from the docs sets the classname to 'Simple', which then loads 'SimplePasswordHasher'.

You might find that having a name of PHPassHasherPasswordHasher is a bit silly, it's up to you what you want to call it.  Perhaps PHPassPasswordHasher might be a bit more appropriate (and then use the classname argument 'PHPass').

**EDIT**: It seems as if Cake has issues when multiple capital letters are used one after the other (eg. PHPass), so the right way to do it is to change the password hasher class to the following:

```
<?php
App::import('Vendor', 'PHPass/class-phpass'); //<--this exists and defines PasswordHash class
class PhpassPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher {

    // functions

}
```

... and make sure the filename matches the classname: PhpassPasswordHasher.php.

Thanks to SDP for the discussion, I learnt something today!

Comment: I've changed the file and class name to PHPassPasswordHasher. How should I reference it for `App::uses()`? Should it be: `App::uses('PHPassPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');`?

Comment: I've updated the code in the question above with the new names. It's still not using my custom class, even with the new names.

Comment: App::uses('PHPassPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth'); seems right to me.

Comment: Do you have xdebug installed?  I'd try stepping through the code to figure out what it's trying to do.

Comment: I don't have xdebug installed at the moment. Can you think of another way to debug which hasher class is getting used? I threw together a /users/add/ action to see what happens and, anecdotally, it's pretty clear that the new user passwords are NOT getting hashed with my custom class. But I'm scratching my head for why the Auth configurations are getting ignored.

Comment: No one has said anything, but I wonder... do I need a custom Authentication object? I'm trying to modify the default behavior as little as possible, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: Personally I used a custom authentication object, which worked well for me -- but the custom hasher function _should_ work.  I can't see what you're doing wrong here.  Are the error or debug log files showing anything?

Comment: I get nothing in the logs. It just silently ignores my custom hasher.

Comment: Additional clue: I experimented by setting various default hashing algorithms as the value for `passwordHasher` (Ex: "Simple", "Blowfish") and then creating users. The hashes which show up in the DB are all the *same* which tells me that my config settings are getting ignored completely.

Comment: What happens if you choose an obviously false password hasher?  You should get an error like 'Password hasher class "JibberJabber" was not found.'

Comment: Same exact hash. No errors. Seems to confirm my theory that those config settings are getting completely ignored.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43384/discussion-between-ben-hitchcock-and-sdp)

Comment: Interesting news! I debugged `$this->settings` inside the constructor of /lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php and my custom hasher settings *are* in there.

Comment: I got it working! We were SO close. See my answer below. If you want to add it into your answer I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs:

> To configure different fields for user in $components array:

```
// Pass settings in $components array
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

[Source](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)

Comment: This looks very promising but `$this->Auth->login()` still returns false. Maybe I'm not using it correctly?

Comment: @SDP see my updated answer, and try add **password** to your `fields` array

Comment: @SDP how are you _debugging_ `$this->Auth->login()`? Could you post some code?

Comment: I'm just storing the return value in a var and debugging it. Also, see my update above. We're on the right track, but I think there's another problem with my custom password hasher configuration. I think it's trying checking the hash with the default algorithm instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working. We were on the right track by renaming the file/class to comply with Cake conventions. I had to go one step further and change the capitalization as well:

```
PHPassPasswordHasher.php --> PhpassPasswordHasher.php
class PHPassPasswordHasher... --> class PhpassPasswordHasher...
```

Phew!

ps: Many many thanks to @Ben Hitchcock for support on this.

Comment: Well done on getting it working!  That would have been very tricky to figure out, especially without remote debugging.